# Can I have an ArrayList of type object that has a list of pointers to objects in Java?

Tags: java, pointers, reference

I currently have three object classes, Transaction, User and Group.. Transaction collects: id, who paid, date, description, amount and an ArrayList of involved users IDs. This works perfectly but adds many lines of code through methods of iterating through users to find which user is who. My question is, could I have an ArrayList *partecipants = new ArrayList; which has the reference of all users ?

```
class Transaction{
    private static AtomicInteger count = new AtomicInteger(0);
    private int id = count.incrementAndGet();
    private String paid;
    private Date date;
    private String message;
    private Double amount;
    private ArrayList<Integer> users = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

Comment: Your "many lines of code" could likely be easily compressed -- why not show us your pertinent [mre] code?

Comment: Yes, but take the example of having 1M users. It's very inefficient iterating to find the one with that ID. So referencing the user in that ArrayList would be nicer I think.. I know it can be done in C but I dont know much about java.

Comment: public String getUserName(int id){//done
  String name=null;
  for(User user: general.users){
   if(user.get_id()==id){
    name=user.get_name();
    break;
   }
  }
  if(name==null){
   ambrogio.sendText("Error");
   return null;
  }else{
   return name;
  }
 }

Comment: Code in comments is not readable, and since it is key to your questions, should not be buried within comments. Please post all code and *important* information in the question itself. The code should be posted as code-formatted text (the editor help will tell you how to do this).

Comment: Sounds like you want a `Map`, something like `Map<Integer, String> usersById = new HashMap<>();`

Comment: @john16384 I'd like to have a list of object users which references/points to the user object while not storing useless information such id and which would make my code simplier instead of iterating through users to match ID when needed.

Comment: A `Map`, such as I suggested, can accomplish that.  No iterating, just do `String userName = usersById.get(id)`.

Comment: Yes, use a Map. Hopefully you have a User class, one that associates each user with his name and ID. The Map key would hold the id's (which should be String, not int), and the Map values would hold the User objects.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels why a string?  He is clearly using ints.

Comment: private Map<Integer,User> users = new Map<Integer,User>; ? but would this be memory consuming or is the reference type I'm asking ?

Comment: @iSpark: memory consuming? Not hardly at all. Don't confuse reference with object.

Comment: @john16384: habit of mine. Original poster, ignore the "String" advise of mine above.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I mean, I wouldn't want this to store the objects as duplicates. Because I already have a class called Storage which keeps the collection.ArrayList<User> users = new ArrayList<User>(); and stores it in the API

Comment: @iSpark: That is the gist of my comment above: you're **not** storing objects but rather storing references to objects, and these are cheap. Use them.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I'm still new to all of this, I just wanted to be sure xD .. Thank you!

Comment: It's also an option to change your `Storage` class to have a `Map<Integer, User>` instead of a `List`, especially if looking things up by id is a common operation.

Comment: @john16384 but in Storage I need to actually store all of them in order to upload them into the API after..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A short example:

Let's say you have a simple `User` class:

```
public class User {
    private int id;
    private String name;

    // etc
}
```

And let's say you originally have a `List` of these:

```
List<User> users;
```

Finding a user by id can be done like this:

```
users.stream().filter(u -> u.getId() == id).findFirst();
```

However, if the users list is large, that can be slow.

You could store the users in a `Map`:

```
Map<Integer, User> usersById;
```

This map would only refer to the other objects, so takes up little space (but still takes up some, it's like an index).

You can fill this map like this:

```
usersById = users.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(User::getId, Function.identity()));
```

Or more traditionally:

```
usersById = new HashMap<>();

for(User u : users) {
    usersById.put(u.getId(), u);
}
```

To find a user by id now, you can use this (with `O(1)` performance):

```
User user = usersById.get(id);
```